# Post a GET request to JIRA with Axios

Tags: reactjs, axios, jira

I am trying to get a response from our corporate jira server. When I call this URL in my browser:

https://jira.intranet.company.com/rest/agile/1.0/epic/key-18/issue, I get a list of all issues in an Epic.

I am trying to duplicate this request in my axios call like this:

```
let axiosUrl = 'https://jira.intranet.company.com/rest/agile/1.0/epic/key-18/issue'
axios({
    baseURL: axiosUrl,
    method: 'get',
    headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        'X-Atlassian-Token':'no-check',
        'Authorization': 'Basic myawesomebase64key',
    },
    //timeout: 2000,

})
    .then((res) => {
        console.log(res.data)
    })
     .catch(function (error) {
         console.log(error);
     });
```

The answer I get is the following:

**Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://jira.intranet.company.com/rest/agile/1.0/epic/key-18/issue' from origin 'http://localhost:9098' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.**

I tried several different things, but I am not sure what is wrong here. How can I post a get request via axios to get the data from my link?

Answer (score 0):

If you want, try to make your web-server to add a header to the requests:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
```

Meaning: the server returns a Access-Control-Allow-Origin header with `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *`, which means that the resource can be accessed by any origin.

More information is available e.g. here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS